# How can I secure my Sinch Application Key

Tags: sinch

I am using Sinch Javascript SDK for voice call where I mention my Application Key that can be access easily and use by anyone. Is there any way to secure my Application Key using PHP?

Answer (score 3):

You can make sure to sign requests on your backend using the authentication scheme documented here: http://www.sinch.com/docs/javascript/user-guide/#authentication 
We will also roll out a new app setting which will allow/disallow client side authentication.